# Can't connect to Docker using Windows Ubuntu App

Tags: python, windows, docker, ubuntu, flask

I am following this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dockerize-your-flask-app/

Everything works well until I get to this step: 
"Build the Docker image
Make sure you are in root directory of the project and run the following command."

To get into the root directory, I enter `sudo su`, then I run the following command as seen in the tutorial:

`sudo docker build --tag flask-docker-demo-app .`

When I run the above, I get this response:

`ERRO[0000] failed to dial gRPC: cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is docker daemon' running on this host?: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: no such file or directory. Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

To carry out these commands, I am using the Ubuntu 18.04 LTS App for windows. I have the Docker Desktop downloaded also.

Additionally, I don't think this has any impact, but I have a different demo.py than the tutorial provides. Here is my demo.py:

````
from flask import Flask 
server = Flask(__name__) 
@server.route('/') 
# ‘/’ URL is bound with hello_world() function. 
def hello_world(): 
    return 'Hello World'

import sys
print(sys.version)

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, server = server, routes_pathname_prefix = '/dash/', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 22], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)```
````

Answer (score 2):

Running the `sudo su` before running your other command is obsolete as it is running as superuser by adding the prefix `sudo`.

"root directory" doesn't mean your root-user directory but the root-directory of your project, where your Dockerfile is stored. You have to navigate to that directory before running the `docker build` command.

Comment: ... however, I have gotten different  messages (not "is the docker daemon running?") when I myself made that mistake.  (As I still do periodically.)  I think the OP has more than one issue here, as I commented above.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your user in the `docker` group so that you do not have to issue `sudo` to use Docker.  (In fact, of course you should *never* do that!)

And then ... "well, *is* the Docker daemon running?"  Looks like you might need to (re-)install it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! When you say (re-)install it, are you referring to the Docker daemon? If so, how would I install the deamon? I thought it would be a setting in the docker windows app.

Additionally, your comment is correct, now when I run without sudo, I get the following error about my requirements.txt file:  `The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code, failed to shutdown container`